# Можно ли использовать переменную типы String в качестве пути для CreateDirectory

Tags: c++, winapi

Суть моего вопроса том что хочу узнать могу ли я использовать переменную типа `string`в качестве пути для `CreateDirectory`

Сейчас у меня есть код:

```
CreateDirectoryA(test111, NULL);
```

Мне нужно чтобы в путь можно было поместить переменную типа `string`

Мне необходимо сделать программу которая получит путь от пользователя и создаст в нем папку, либо если это возможно программа в месте где ее запустили создаст эту папку. Рассмотрю любые ответа,спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если надо передавать `char*`, а есть `string` - используйте метод `.c_str()`...

Comment: Используйте `<filesystem>`